# Difference when hashing page source with Node and Python

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, hash, python-requests, puppeteer

**Goal:**
To hash page source in order to detect changes between scheduled scraping.

**Python code:**

```
import requests
import hashlib

url = 'http://example.org/'

r = requests.get(url, verify=False,)
r.encoding = 'utf-8'

print(hashlib.sha256(r.text.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest())
```

Result: `ea8fac7c65fb589b0d53560f5251f74f9e9b243478dcb6b3ea79b5e36449c8d9`

**Node & Puppeteer code:**

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
var crypto = require('crypto');

(async()=> {
    const browser= await puppeteer.launch();
    const page= await browser.newPage();

    try {
        const response = await page.goto('http://example.org/', { waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded', timeout: 30000 });
        console.log(crypto.createHash('sha256').update(response.text().toString()).digest('hex'));
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e.message);
    }
    await browser.close();
})();
```

Result: `b4e6060006b920bc021110ea8ab8d67744983e2b7ff75e1c8be5613af93f687d`

**Questions:**

1. Why is there a difference? As far as I inspected, both methods
   return the same response.
2. Can I get same results?
3. Are there a better ways to detect changes in page content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to await the response text in puppeteer, otherwise you are hashing the stringified version of `Promise { <pending> }`

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
var crypto = require('crypto');

(async()=> {
    const browser= await puppeteer.launch();
    const page= await browser.newPage();

    try {
        const response = await page.goto('http://example.org/', { waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded', timeout: 30000 });
        const source = await response.text();
        console.log(crypto.createHash('sha256').update(source).digest('hex'));
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e.message);
    }
    await browser.close();
})();
```

Output:

```
python c.py
ea8fac7c65fb589b0d53560f5251f74f9e9b243478dcb6b3ea79b5e36449c8d9
node c.js
ea8fac7c65fb589b0d53560f5251f74f9e9b243478dcb6b3ea79b5e36449c8d9
```

Comment: Thanks! I inspected with `await response.text()`, but forgot to include it in hashing function.